# When should I use the keyword "typename" when using templates

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, typename

I've been working lately on a small project, and I couldn't figure out something..

I've been given a .h file that was containing a class, using a typename template. Inside that class there was a private class.

```
template <typename T>
class Something
{
public:
        Something();
        ~Something();

        Node* Function1(int index);
        int Index(const T& id);


private:
        class Node()
        {
                public:
                T id;

                //Imagine the rest for the Node


        };      
};
```

The problem occured when I wanted to define the functions of the class "Something"

Here's how I was doing it (in a .inl file)

```
template<typename T>
Node* Something::Function1(int index) //Is the return type well written?
{
        // returns the node at the specified index
}

template<typename T>
int Something::Index(const T& id) //Is the parameter type well specified?
{
        // returns the index of the node with the specified id
}
```

So the bugging part was in the definitions part... Do I have to tell the compiler that the return type (in this case Node*) uses the typename template (like this: `typename Node*`) ? And what about the parameter ? `typename const Node&` ?

So basically, when do I have to specify wether the function/parameter uses a template?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please post sinppets into your question!

Comment: I've posted links with snippets. I couldn't figure out how to indent my snippets correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
typename Something<T>::Node * Something::Function1(int index) //Is the return type well written?
{
        // returns the node at the specified index
}
```

Comment: Ok, and what about the parameter type of the other method?

Comment: `Node` is a nested class name. So you can't use it unless you're in code for a method of `Something<T>` or you use the full `typename Something<T>::Node` name. And a method return type (defined outside the class) is not yet "in" a method of `Something`, so you have to make it clear to the compiler.  The other method won't have any such issue, because the compiler always knows what `int` means.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and for taking time.

Answer (score 5):

For `Function1`, you need to tell the compiler what Node is -- in this case, it's a nested type inside `Something<T>`. Because it's dependent on `T` (it's a dependent name), you need to tell the compiler it's a type, so you must write it as `typename Something<T>::Node`. The issue is that there might be some `T` for which `Something<T>::Node` isn't actually a type (i.e. if you partially specialize `Something<T>`).

For `Index`, what you have is fine -- `const T&` is just a reference to a `const T`, and the compiler knows what `T` is.

Comment: so if the parameter were a pointer to a node, I'd have to specify the typename part again, right?

Comment: Since you're within `Something<T>`, you could just write `Node *`. But if you wrote it out explicitly, you'd need to say `typename Something<T>::Node *` rather than just `Something<T>::Node *`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and for taking time.

Answer (score 3):

The simple rule: You need to use the `typename` keyword every time you name a type using the `Class::Type` syntax, if the `Class` part depends on a template parameter.  (The `Class` part might be a template parameter, or it might be a `typedef` in your class template, etc.)

Edit: There's also some confusion about nested class scoping rules.  This is mostly independent of the `typename` issue, so here's a non-template example.

```
class Outer {
public:
  class Inner {
  };
  Inner* func(Inner* obj);
};

Outer::Inner* func(Inner* obj)
{
}
```

The full name of `Inner` is `Outer::Inner`.  But you can also use the shorter name `Inner` anywhere from the scope of class `Outer`, including all of the declaration of `func`.  At the definition of `func`, the return type is NOT in the scope of `Outer`, so the full name is necessary.  But after the `(`, the function parameters ARE in the scope of `Outer`, so the short name is okay.

Combining this with the template-ness of the original example, since the equivalent of `Outer` is `Something<T>`, you need the `typename` keyword to say `Something<T>::Node`.

Comment: so the parameter type in the definition of the function Index should be written typename const Class<T>::Node& id ?

Comment: @Pacane: That depends, do you want to pass a `T` or a `Node`?  If you do want to pass a `Node`, the full version will work, but is not needed, since the compiler just saw you're defining a `Something` method, and `const Node&` would be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and for taking time.

Comment: Edited with an explanation of class scope in member definitions.

Answer (score 1):

`typename` and `class` are equivalent in template type parameter list:

```
template <class T> class C;
```

is the same as

```
template <typename T> class C;
```

Where the `typename` is required is when referring to [***dependent names***](http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#disambiguation):

```
template <typename T> struct A {
    typedef typename T::some_type container;
};
```

Comment: Actually, typename and class are NOT equivalent in a parameter list.  The typename keyword can't replace 'class' when expecting template template parameters.

Comment: Yes, thanks, forgot about this. Though it's just a boo-boo on the part of the language - they just forgot about that case same as I here :)