# Templates: I need to learn these better? Why am i getting errors

Tags: c++, templates

I am working on someone elses code that is no longer around and it is old CodeWarrior Code. XCode complains about this:

```
template <class listClass,class itemClass>
void FxStreamingObjectList<listClass,itemClass>::StreamOut(FxStream *stream)
{
    if (listClass::size())
    {
        stream->PutSeparator();
        stream->PutString(mFieldName.c_str());
        stream->PutSeparator();
        stream->PutBeginList();
        stream->Indent(+1);

        listClass::iterator iter;

        for (iter=listClass::begin(); iter != listClass::end(); iter++)
        {
            stream->PutSeparator();
            stream->PutString( (*iter)->GetClassID() );
        }

            (*iter)->StreamOut(stream);
        }
        stream->Indent(-1);
        stream->PutSeparator();
        stream->PutEndList();
        stream->PutSeparator();
}
```

}

I get errors on `listClass::iterator iter;` and `for (iter=listClass::begin(); iter != listClass::end(); iter++)` that are:

```
error: expected `;' before 'iter'
error: 'iter' was not declared in this scope
```

Other places in the same .h, same types of template declarations I get errors like:

```
error: dependent-name 'listClass::iterator' is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type
```

at:

`for (listClass::iterator iter=listClass::begin(); iter != listClass::end(); iter++)`

How do I go about solving these errors? I dont know templates all that well so I am confused and not sure where to begin. A good template resource is also appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put "template" and "typename" on dependent names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I use the keyword "typename" when using templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227833/when-should-i-use-the-keyword-typename-when-using-templates)

Comment: Not duplicates. This question is completely the reverse of both of those!

Comment: @Tomalak - Strange then that the answers are the same.

Comment: @BoPersson: That the answers are the same does not mean that the questions are the same.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler doesn't know until a bit later in the parsing process that the specific `listClass` for any particular instantiation of `FxStreamingObjectList<listClass, itemClass>` has a member type called `iterator`. The name `iterator` is therefore a "dependent name".

[You must hint](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html) to the compiler that you expect/require `iterator` here to be a type, with the `typename` keyword:

```
typename listClass::iterator iter;
```

and:

```
for (typename listClass::iterator it = listClass::begin(), end = listClass::end(); it != end; ++it)
```

<sup>(BTW, are `begin()` and `end()` *really* static member functions?)</sup>

Just another C++ quirk. :)

Comment: Just 40 seconds ahead of me! Bad Bad. +1

Comment: @Tomalak: I think yours is better, with the explanation you provided. So I deleted mine, as it isn't needed anymore.

Comment: @Tomalak, so anyplace listClass is used I need to prefix with `typename` so the compiler gets the the face it is a type? Still slightly confused with how the chain of events occurs.

Comment: @Tomalak - Do I need to change my `for` loop above for more than adding `typename` I get a new error: `error: invalid type in declaration before '=' token` when I do `for (typename iter=listClass::begin(); iter != listClass::end(); iter++)`

Comment: @Tomalak - that is how the code is with `begin()` and `end()` I thought it was just `begin` and `end` so I need to find how they are using this. maybe something custom but they picked a bad naming convention

Comment: @JTO: You forgot `listClass::iterator`.

Comment: @JTO: You only need `typename` before a "dependent name". Follow the link in my answer for a detailed discussion on when and where you need this.

Answer (score 1):

Officially C++ does not know whether dependent symbols are types or otherwise.  To you the programmer `listClass::iterator` is obviously a type.  The compiler needs some help.

The definition of `iter` should be:

```
typename listClass::iterator iter
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers already answered ***Why the Error***
As for the second part of your the Question:  ***A good template resource is also appreciated***

The most definitive book on C++ Templates is:
**C++ Templates: The Complete Guide** by ***David Vandevoorde & Nicolai Josuttis***