# c++ template and iterator

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I am trying to declare this function :

```
template <typename T> void hi(std::map<T,double> m,std::vector<std::map<T,double>::iterator > vec)
{
    //....
}
```

I want the function to have as parameters a map of  and a vector of iterators on this map. But the g++ compiler does not seem to like it and I receive the following error :

```
 type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp,     class _Alloc> class std::vector’
: error:   expected a type, got ‘std::map::iterator’
: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

Any help please?

Comment: You must use `typename`

Comment: I already use it in my declaration, but perhaps you mean something else.. Can you be more explicit please?

Comment: BTW, do you really want to pass such big data structures by-value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must [write `typename` before the iterator argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227833/when-should-i-use-the-keyword-typename-when-using-templates)

```
template <typename T> 
void hi(std::map<T,double> m, std::vector<typename  std::map<T,double>::iterator > vec)
                                          ^^^^^^^^
{
    //....
}
```

Yes, it is unfortunate that `typename` has 2 different meanings. Some authors use `template<class T>` for precisely that reason, in order to visually disambiguate template parameter declarations from dependent type extraction. Especially in template-metaprogramming this can help to make code a bit more readable.

Comment: You're wrong. You need `typename` here: `std::vector< !!! typename !!! std::map<T,double>::iterator`

Comment: @borisbn sorry, updated, you were right, I typed it too early. The nested `std::map` had dropped off my screen when I wrote the answer, so I thought it showed a `std::vector<double>::iterator` :-)

Comment: @volatile If this answer helped you, please consider taking the effort to [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/192808) (equally applies to most of your other questions).