# why this typedef is not recognized when the child class is template?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance

This code compiles perfectly :

```
# include <iostream>
# include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
class HasThisClass
{
    protected:
        typedef T ThisClass;
};

class Foo : private HasThisClass<Foo>
{
    public:
        static void printName()
        { std::cout << typeid(ThisClass).name() << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo::printName();
    return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't compile :

```
# include <iostream>
# include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
class HasThisClass
{
    protected:
        typedef T ThisClass;
};

template <typename T>
class Bar : private HasThisClass<Bar<T>>
{
    public:
        static void printName()
        { std::cout << typeid(ThisClass).name() << std::endl; } // ERROR here
};

int main()
{
    Bar<double>::printName();
    return 0;
}
```

with the following error:

> error: ‘ThisClass’ was not declared in this scope

**I don't understand why it doesn't work when the `Bar` class is template. How can I obtain the expected behaviour ?**

*Note 1: I don't want to solve the problem by calling `typeid(Bar<double>).name()` or `typeid(typename HasThisClass<Bar<double>>::ThisClass).name()` because in my case the call to `ThisClass` is written by a macro.*

*Note 2: If you know another way to manipulate the local class type in a static function, it could solve my problem.*

*Note 3: I don't use C++14 or >=*

Comment: You can use `typeid(typename Bar<T>::ThisClass).name()`, is that any good to you?

Comment: Seems relevant, even though the question it answers is not really a duplicate: [A: When should I use the keyword “typename” when using templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4227917).

Comment: The relevant go-to question is [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245) but that is a lot of reading. Useful, but give yourself plenty of time.